# How to refresh data in StringGrid when sorting DB using ADOTable.Sort

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal, tstringgrid, tadotable

I have a TStringGrid in a Firemonkey app for Windows which I have used LiveBindings to connect to a DataSource.

The DataSource is linked to an ADOTable. When I use ADOTable.sort the data in the Grid seems to only sort the first row and not the entire table/grid.

Does anyone know how to refresh the entire grid, or ensure all the data is sorted.

ADOTable.filter refreshes the entire grid, so why doesn't sort work?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but rather a workaround.

I placed a TBindNavigator on my form and set Visible to false.
Then I programatically clicked the refresh button when I need the TStringGrid to update:

BindNavigator1.BtnClick(nbRefresh);

This updates the entire grid.

NOTE: Refreshing the DataSet (DataSet.refresh) did not work.